# A body rotating around a fixed axis relative to another rotating body

Tags: rotational-kinematics, rotation, angular-velocity

A question in my book goes as follows:

> A planet P revolves around the Sun in a circular orbit, with the Sun at the center, which is co-planar with and concentric to the circular orbit of Earth E around the Sun. P and E revolve in the same direction. The times required for the revolution of P and E around the Sun are $T_\mathrm{P}$ and $T_\mathrm{E}$. Let $T_\mathrm{S}$ be the time required for P to make one revolution around the Sun relative to E: show that $\dfrac{1}{T_\mathrm{S}} = \dfrac{1}{T_\mathrm{E}} - \dfrac{1}{T_\mathrm{P}}.$ Assume $T_\mathrm{P} > T_\mathrm{E}$

What does '*the time required by planet P to revolve around the Sun relative to the Earth*' mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation of this statement is that your reference frame is on Earth, $T_S$ is how long it takes for another planet $P$ to come back to the same spot relative to the Earth.

Let's take an example: $P$ is the planet Mars

The period of the Earth $T_P=365.25$ days. The period of Mars $T_P=687$ days (a quick Google search). By the formula, $\frac{1}{T_S}=\frac{1}{365.25}-\frac{1}{687}\Rightarrow T_S=779.8$ days

This is the time required by Mars to revolve around the Sun relative to Earth, for example, the time between two closest approaches of Mars.

[According to NASA](https://mars.nasa.gov/all-about-mars/night-sky/close-approach/), the time between two closest approaches of Mars is $26$ months $\approx 793$ days (if we assume an average month has $30.5$ days).

Proof:

[image]

[Source of picture](https://astro.unl.edu/naap/ssm/ssm_advanced.html#:%7E:text=Deriving%20the%20Synodic%20Period%20Formula&text=If%20E%20is%20the%20sidereal,period%20of%20the%20superior%20planet.)

We know that, looking at the Earth's orbit, that $\theta=(T_S-T_E)(\frac{2\pi}{T_E})$ ($T_S-T_E$ is the time it takes for the Earth to moves through the angle and we know that the angle is $T\frac{2\pi}{T_E}$, where $T_E$ is the sidereal period, the "real" period of the Earth, $1$ year).

Looking at the planet's orbit, that $\theta=T_S\frac{2\pi}{T_P}$.

Equate the two expressions for $\theta$, and we get
$(T_S-T_E)(\frac{2\pi}{T_E})=T_S\frac{2\pi}{T_P}$. Divide by $2\pi$, and bring the $T_S$ down, we get $\frac{T_S-T_E}{T_ET_S}=\frac{1}{T_P}$, and we get $\frac{1}{T_P}=\frac{1}{T_E}-\frac{1}{T_S}$.
[Proof came from here](https://astro.unl.edu/naap/ssm/ssm_advanced.html#:%7E:text=Deriving%20the%20Synodic%20Period%20Formula&text=If%20E%20is%20the%20sidereal,period%20of%20the%20superior%20planet.)

Comment: "My interpretation of this statement is that your reference frame is on Earth, $T_P$ is how long it takes for another planet P to come back to the same spot relative to the Earth." Do you mean $T_S$ over here? Also, why is $T_S$ different from $T_P$?

Comment: @ThePixelGenome Yes, I have fixed it. Thank you! Also, $T_S$ is relative to Earth, which is moving. $T_P$ is relative to the Sun, which is not moving (just a good approximation).

Comment: Ah I understand. How would we derive this formula though? I'll accept your answer if you could include a derivation of the formula.

Comment: I think a picture would help to explain the question

Comment: I think this interpretation is correct - it's essentially the time it takes for one planet to "lap" another by overtaking it in orbit. Closest/furthest approaches between the two bodies are convenient, unique points to check for the same relative positioning.

Comment: @ThePixelGenome I have added a derivation.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the derivation. It answers my questions, although it does have one or two formatting errors. But I guess, that's fine! So, I'll be accepting this answer.

Answer (score -1):

What does **the time required by planet P to revolve around the Sun relative to the Earth** mean?

That's your basic question.
To which the answer is
It means the time required by P (which moves slower than E because itá distance to the center of the circle is bigger than the distance of E to the center, which means it has more distance to cover and on top of that, P's velocity is smaller: $\frac{mv^2}{r}=G\frac{mM}{r^2}$, so $v=G\sqrt{\frac{M}{r}}$ ) to make one revolution relative to the time it takes E to make (obviously) more than one revolutions.

Depending on both the distances of E ($r_E$) and P ($r_P$) you can calculate the difference in their rotation times.